# Intersection of Dense Set with set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a problem with proof of this fact:

X - closed set. Y is dense closed set in X => $ X \cap Y $ is dense set in X too . When X and Y is opened sets its work, but I don`t know how proof with closed.Please help

Comment: A set $Y$ is dense and closed iff it is the whole space $X$.

Comment: Why ? Set is dense, when X ⊂ closed Y

Comment: A set is dense in $X$ when its closure is $X$. But if it's also closed it equals its closure. So the set already equals $X$.

Comment: Set Y is dense in X, when X ⊂ closed Y, here is an еmbedding, not equality

Comment: Not quite, if $Y \subseteq X$, $Y$ is dense in $X$ iff $\operatorname{cl}_X(Y)=X$ iff $X \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(Y)$ where the last closure is taken in the whole space (of which $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces). So it depends on where you take the closure, I was referring to closure within $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Since Y is a dense closed subset  of X, $ Y= X$. So $\overline {X \cap Y} = \overline X= X$.